# Can I schedule python script on SQL Server Management studio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssms

I am working on automating exception mail using python script. I have written code on python to connect and extract data from SQL Server database then customize the output using python script and uses python library to send mail to define user.

I want to schedule this script to run daily using sql server management studio. I search on internet/stackoverflow but I am getting detail about running python script on SSMS but nothing about scheduling the script. How can I achieve this task?